# Serially correlated independent variables

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics, assumptions

My question is very similar to [Serially Correlated Regressors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160421/serially-correlated-regressors).

None of the answers there answer the central point of the question. Is it at all a problem if independent variables, are serially correlated?

Literature deals with serial correlation of residuals, and the problems it poses, a lot. But I found no literature that deals with, or even speaks about serial correlation of regressors. That makes me feel it doesn't matter.

But need some expert to prove or illustrate it.