# What is the effect of autocorrelation on R² in OLS

Tags: regression, least-squares, autocorrelation

I was wondering. What would be the effect of the presence of autocorrelation on R² or R²_adjusted? Especially in a dataset used in multiple linear regression?

edit: So the correlation of each variable with itself in time.

Comment: A somewhat related question: ["$R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$ in presence of overlapping observations"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432173).

Comment: Similar https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160421/serially-correlated-regressors. Although not a good answer provided.

Comment: Yet another vaguely related post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331139/showing-that-r-squared-might-not-be-useful-in-time-series-data

Comment: Can you clarify the effect *relative to what* you are interested in?